# How to execute a function into my app after redirect to an OAuth page?

Tags: ios, swift, http-method

I have this method in http to be triggered after the authentication by OAuth is done. Basically my app is being redirected to a native app to authenticate, however I need to send the information it receives to the backend. So I did this function.

```
 func sendAuth() {
        if let url = NSURL(string: "https://xxxxxx/api/v1/integrations/xxxx/auth"){
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
            let session = ServicesUtils.BaseSessionManager()
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            let token = AccessToken?()
            let json = ["token" : (token?.tokenString)!, "refresh_token" : (token?.refreshToken)!, "expires_in" : (token?.expirationDate)!, "user_id" : "user_uuid"  , "token_type" : "Bearer"] as Dictionary <String,AnyObject>
            let data: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(json)
            request.HTTPBody = data
            session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            }).resume()

        }
```

How could I throw this function after the redirect was made back to my app?

Comment: using url schemes: http://jayeshkawli.ghost.io/ios-custom-url-schemes/

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs problem is my app redirect into a native app for use OAuth then back to my app normally but crashes due to function it is being perfomed before this way. Correct is: Go to native app and authorized OAuth > Back my app and send POST request to backend